# ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY how does it actually work?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I have the following code:

```
try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","VENIVIDIVICI");
        Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM example184"))
{
    rs.absolute(2);
    rs.absolute(1);
    rs.beforeFirst();

while (rs.next())
{
    System.out.println(rs.getString("iD"));

}
    while(rs.previous())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("Id"));
    }
}
catch(SQLException sql ){System.out.println(sql);}

}
```

It should give a SQLException since it's only `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, instead it works fine without throwing any exception.

**UPDATE:** As Aleroot suggested in the below response, I have tried the following modifications:

```
try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","VENIVIDIVICI");
        Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM example184"))
{

    st.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        rs.afterLast();
while (rs.previous())
{
    System.out.println(rs.getString("iD"));

}

}
catch(SQLException sql ){System.out.println(sql);}

}
}
```

without success, it still compiles and run properly.

Thanks,
 Indeed ItIs

Answer (score 1):

**TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY** *means that the ResultSet can only be navigated forward. You cannot move backwards in the ResultSet*.

In this case I think the call to `previous()` is allowed because is cached, try to change the fetch size :

```
st.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Or to read the resultset from the end to the start without previously reading from start to end(with next) ...

To move backward try :

```
rs.afterLast()
while (rs. previous())
{
    System.out.println(rs.getString("iD"));

}
```

If it in both cases the driver keep executing without throwing the SQLException, it could be a bug of the driver you are using...

Comment: @I have tried both of them and it still works, I am updating the question with the code

Comment: What version of the JDBC driver are you using ?

Comment: JDBC 4.1 mysql driver 5.1

Comment: Try with the : mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin

Comment: So the final answer is that is driver dependent?

Comment: Tried with this one http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.25 and it still works..

Comment: Try with another database type like for example postgresql and if it throws the exception, open an incident bug on MySQL bug reporting site.

Comment: Do you get an exception using mysql connector?

Comment: I can't try at the moment.